# Is it possible to get only one column value from an Azure table?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I am communicating with an azure table using C#. I am curious if there is a way to only get one value instead of returning an entire entity?

Say I only want to get the timestamp of the row. Is there a way to retrieve only the timestamp that matches with the keys, or do I have to use an entire entity?

Here's an example of what I mean:

Can I do something like this:

```
DateTime time = table.Retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey, Timestamp);
```

or do I have to do this:

```
MyClass object = table.Retrieve(partitionKey, rowKey).Result as MyClass;
Console.WriteLine(object.TimeStamp);
```

I am trying to avoid writing a different class or adding new attributes for each possible entity that could be entered into my table.

Comment: `Timestamp` is a standard field right?  Maybe just make a generic extension method that allows you to get the timestamp of any entity

Comment: But what if later on I want to retrieve a different, non-standard field?

Comment: What version of the storage SDK are you working with? Can you link docs to the `Retrieve` method you're calling? I'm familiar w/ the `TableOperation.Retrieve` method but not one that directly returns TableEntities (the one you're using)

Comment: I mean in any case you have to get the entire object.  Its all stored as JSON.  But you can write a function that gives you the specific thing you want so you are keeping your code DRY

Comment: I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v9.2.0

Comment: [TableOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet)

Comment: Ok, so you are using `TableOperation`. The code in the question snippet doesn't make sense to me. Usage as I understand it is as follows - create a `TableOperetaion` first via Retrieve call (just creates the opearation, doesn't execute it), then you call `Execute` on your table object passing in the created operation.

`
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SomeEntity>("partitionkey", "rowkey");

// Execute the retrieve operation.
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);`

Comment: I'm aware of how it works, I was too busy to write an actual working example. I was just wanting to get my point across.

Comment: That's confusing to people that understand the SDK - I can't tell if you're just shortening, or if you've written a custom `Retrieve` extension method that behaves differently than library methods. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `DynamicTableEntity`. You can cast the result of your `Execute` call to a `DynamicTableEntity` and access default properties like `Timestamp`, `RowKey`, etc. The type also contains a definition for `Properties`, a `Dictionary` of (string=column name) -> (value=a TableEntityProperty encapsulating any custom data.

As far as retrieving a subset of the properties in storage, you can pass a 3rd parameter to `TableOperation.Retrieve` which specifies the subset of custom properties to retrieve when the call is executed.

```
//table is a CloudTable object
List<string> propertiesToRetrieve = new List<string>() { "MyIntProperty"}
TableOperation op = TableOperation.Retrieve("partitionkey", "rowkey", propertiesToRetrieve);
TableResult result = table.Execute(op);
DynamicTableEntity myEntity = (DynamicTableEntity)result.Result;
DateTime ts = myEntity.Timestamp;
int? customIntProperty = myEntity.Properties["MyIntProperty"].Int32Value;
```